# Which xscreensaver program was run last?

Tags: linux, xorg, xscreensaver

I use XScreensaver to lock my screen with all screensavers enabled in a random rotation. I often come back to my laptop and wonder which screensaver I was just looking at (to configure the options for it, or just to run it again and get a better look)

How can I figure out which one was most recently run?

Bonus points: I have 2 monitors, and xscreensaver plays a different screen saver on each (still random). Is there a way to determine both?

Answer (score 1):

I'm optimistic that xscreensaver will record its screen saver choices into a log file if
the right logging/debugging options are enabled. I haven't had a chance to try this yet, but will update if/when I do.
 https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XScreenSaver#Debugging

Comment: This works; I see the screensavers being spawned in the log. Unfortunately it also prints the log on the screensaver, which is a bit unsightly.

Comment: Did you use both these settings? I'd like to try reproducing what you saw. xscreensaver.logFile:/var/log/xscreensaver.log
xscreensaver.verbose:true

Comment: This was with xscreensaver -verbose (I haven't used the logfile yet, but I doubt that would affect it). I haven't got a chance to restart X to test out the X resource changes

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer is that running xscreensaver-demo immediately will highlight the screensaver last used on one of the monitors.